# wpf custom combobox with datagrid but after popup dorpdown the first item is not selected

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, selection

i have customed a wpf combobox with a datagrid in it.

After you click the toggle button of the combobox, it will open the dropdown popup and show the datagrid like the image below.
[cilck the toggle buttom to show the whole result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tadiv.png)

Now my question is why the first item in the datagrid in the dropdown popup is not selected?And if after i press the down arrow key, it will select the second(like the image below [press the down arrow key right after the dropdown shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d1JK.png)) item which makes me fell that the first item is somehow selected but the highlight background is not shown.
Is this about the focus or anything else? Really no idea here , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a code for reproducing the issue?